# Demonstration congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

> Assuming that $m=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_r^{\alpha_r}$. Show that $$a\equiv b\pmod m\Longleftrightarrow a\equiv b\pmod {p_i^{\alpha_i}},\;i={1,...,r}$$

I always thought very beautiful statements that contain numbers in this way $$x=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}p_3^{\alpha_3}p_4^{\alpha_4}...p_w^{\alpha_w}$$and to be here studying congruences, came across eats this issue, which unfortunately do not even know where to start or what to do ... While statements like these, I can not understand them very easily so I ask YOU DO ***PLEASE DETAILED*** ...

I thank you ..

Comment: Start with a simple case: try to show that if $\gcd(c,d)=1$, then $a\equiv b\pmod{cd}$ if and only if $a\equiv b\pmod c$ and $a\equiv b\pmod d$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, but I can not do such a demonstration. $:'($

Comment: Can you show that if $a\equiv b\pmod{rs}$, then $a\equiv b\pmod r$?

Comment: I honestly can not understand. : (

Comment: OK, let's go back a step. What does $a\equiv b\pmod m$ mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson means that $m\mid (a-b)$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10912/discussion-between-marcelolpjunior-and-gerry-myerson)

Comment: Good! Now let's go back to showing if $a\equiv b \pmod{rs}$ then $a\equiv b\pmod r$. What happens when you just use the definition you have just written? Sorry, I don't do chat.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $$a\equiv b\pmod {rs}\Longrightarrow rs\mid(a-b)\Longrightarrow\\\exists k\in\mathbb{N}\mid a-b \Longrightarrow \\a-b=rsk \Longrightarrow$$$$r\mid (a-b)\;\;\text{and}\;\;s\mid (a-b)$$

Comment: $a-b=rsk=r(sk)$ implies $r\mid a-b$, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think this as I did above, lol, pretty simple, but I had not realized!!

Comment: OK. Well, that should help you do the "if" part of your original question. The "only if" part is a little harder. You need to show that if $\gcd(c,d)=1$ and $c\mid a$ and $d\mid a$ then $cd\mid a$. But any introductory number theory textbook should help you with that. When you have figured it out, come back and write it up as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can not produce this "back" answer, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did the "if" you can see if this correct?

Comment: Looks good. Now, let's look at the other part. If $c$ and $d$ are relatively prime and both divide $x$, then $x=cr$ for some $r$, and $x=ds$ for some $s$, so $cr=ds$, so $c\mid ds$. Now have you seen a theorem that tells you what you can conclude from $c\mid ds$ and $\gcd(c,d)=1$?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at this some more?

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1: if $c$ and $d$ are coprime and both divide $x$, then their product divides $x$.

Proof: on the hypotheses, $x=cr=ds$ for some integers $r,s$, so $c$ divides $ds$. That, with $c$ being coprime to $d$, implies (by a standard result) that $c$ divides $s$, so $s=ct$ for some integer $t$, so $x=cdt$, so $cd$ divides $x$.

Lemma 2: if $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_r$ are pairwise coprime, and all divide $x$, then their product divides $x$.

Proof: by induction on $r$, with Lemma 1 providing the base of the induction.

Theorem: if $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_r$ are distinct primes, and $m=p_1^{u_1}p_2^{u_2}\times\cdots\times p_r^{u_r}$, and $a\equiv b\pmod{p_i^{u_i}}$ for all $i$, then $a\equiv b\pmod m$.

Proof: the numbers $p_i^{u_i}$ are pairwise coprime, so Lemma 2 applies.

Answer (score 0):

> $(\Longrightarrow)\\a\equiv b\pmod m\Longrightarrow a\equiv b\pmod{p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_r^{\alpha_r}}$
>
> Be $m=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_i^{\alpha_i}...p_r^{\alpha_r}$, with $i=1,...,r$ then, knowing that $$\text{If}\;\;(p_i^{\alpha_i},p_j^{\alpha_j})=1\;\text{with}\;\;i\neq j\;\;\text{and}\;\;j=1,...,r$$As $a\equiv b\pmod m$, then $m\mid (a-b)$, implies $p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_r^{\alpha_r}\mid (a-b)$, implies $a-b=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_r^{\alpha_r}\cdot k$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then$$a-b=p_i^{\alpha_i}(p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_r^{\alpha_r}\cdot k)\Longrightarrow p_i^{\alpha_i}\mid (a-b)\Longrightarrow a\equiv b\pmod {p_i^{\alpha_i}}$$$\Box$$$$$Correct?

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Show that if $(n_1,n_2)=1$, then $n_1\cdot n_2|(a-b)$ if and only if $n_1|(a-b)$ and $n_2|(a-b)$.